# Angular 2 -> how to hide controls using FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to control visibility of controls using FormGroup (TypeScript Angular 2).

I'm manage to write the following code:

```
this.myDoch.controls['text1'].disable();
```

but it only blocked the control, I'm looking for hide the contorl.

Thanks.

Comment: you can dynamically [remove](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#removeControl-anchor) and [add](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#addControl-anchor) control to formgroup.. not sure if fits your usecase

Comment: You can always put [ngModelOptions] = {standalone:true} in the html with an *ngIf condition. Now with angular4 you can put *ngIf - else bolck in html.

Comment: suraj - add or remove control only disconnect the connection between the control in the template and the FormControl object in class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `disabled` like this:

#### HTML

```
<input [ngClass]="{'hidden': link.controls.title.disabled}" type="text" formControlName="title" />
```

#### component.ts

```
linkArry.controls[0].disable();
```

#### CSS

`.hidden {display:none;}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'disabled' css selector.
For example :

```
.my-input:disabled {
    display:none;
}
```

You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp).

Comment: I don't want to see the control on the page.

Comment: You wont, it will be invisible to the user.