# Toggle FormControl in View with Formbuilder Typescript using Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

How do I remove elements from a HTML DOM View with NgIf using Typescript, not html? Looking for similar syntax.

Prefer to iterate through an Array in typescript, and remove items from the view, rather than wrapping all 20 formcontrols with NgIf, seems kind of repetitive.

Currently using Formbuilder, not FormArray. This link places style display none, which is not ideal practice in Angular from what I read. Is that true?

[Angular 2 -> how to hide controls using FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025499/angular-2-how-to-hide-controls-using-formgroup?rq=1)

We have exclusion array, and prefer to disable with foreach in Typescript

Maybe something like this?

This only disables the field, still shows in html View

```
Object.keys(this.customerForm.controls).forEach(key => {
     if (this.excludeFormControlArray.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
         this.customerForm.get(key).disable;  // This only disables the field, still shows in html View


this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'firstName': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50), PhoneNumberValidator]],
  'phoneNumber': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50), PhoneNumberValidator]],
  'streetName': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50), PhoneNumberValidator]],

  'emailAddress': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.email]],
  'city': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)]],
  'state': [null, [Validators.maxLength(200)]],
  'zip':[null,[Validators.maxLength(200)]]
});
```

**HTML**

//trying to prevent wrapping each with ngIf, items are placed in special ,location on page, due to UX wireframe specs, NgFor was not entirely possible, html/css view is lot more complicated than this,

```
<div class = "row">
    <app-input-textbox  formControlName = "firstName"></app-input-textbox>
<div class = "row">
<div class = "column">
    <app-input-textbox  formControlName = "emailAddress"></app-input-textbox>
</div>
<div class = "test">
    <app-input-textbox  formControlName = "state"></app-input-textbox>
    <app-input-textbox  formControlName = "zip"></app-input-textbox>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide working example on stalkbliz ?

Comment: well I don't even have working example for solution, this question can be applied to any form with multiple fields

Comment: If you don't have an operation on it, why are you form creating object for it

Comment: Do you want to hide or show formcontrol?

Comment: I really unable to understand what you want! 1) Do you want to disable firstName from TS code?

Comment: to disable a FormControl, you need use the "method" disable() -you forget the parenthesis- https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable. You can always use a `*ngIf="form.get('name').enabled"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you want to create a "app-input". My suggest is that the app-input inject as constructor FormGroupDirective, and use directly [formControl] see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjetkw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngIf="control && control.enabled">
  {{label}}
  <input [formControl]="control">
  </ng-container>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  constructor( @Optional() @Host() private form:FormGroupDirective){}
  control:FormControl
  @Input() set name(value)
  {
    this.control=this.form?this.form.form.get(value) as FormControl:null
  }
  @Input() label: string;
}
```

This allow us has a form like

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <app-input name="one" label="One"></app-input>
  <app-input name="two" label="Two"></app-input>
</form>
```

If we want to add errors we can improve the app-input, use a input and a function to get the first error among the errors

```
  @Input() errors:any={} //see that, by defect it's an empty object

  getError()
  {
    for (let key of Object.keys(this.errors))
    {
       if (this.control.hasError(key))
            return this.errors[key]
    }
  }
```

And add to the template some like

```
  <div *ngIf="control.touched">
    {{getError()}}
  </div>
```

Our main-app becomes like, e.g.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <app-input name="one" label="One" [errors]="{required:'One is required'}"></app-input>
  <app-input name="two" label="Two"></app-input>
</form>
```

Well, this it's only an example, I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfsoux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for you.
Here I am using custom model (array) to render fields:

```
<h1>My dynamic form</h1>
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div *ngFor="let input of inputList">
    <label>{{ input.label }}</label>
    <input type="{{ input.type }}" formControlName="{{ input.formControlName }}">
    <span (click)="removeInputField(input)">Remove</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addInputField()">Add Input Field</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is two methods to add and remove controls:

```
  addInputField() {
    const formControlName = prompt("FormControlName input: ");
    const inputType = prompt("Type input: ");
    const label = prompt("Label input: ");
    const inputData = {
      inputType: inputType,
      formControlName: formControlName,
      label: label
    };
    this.inputList.push(inputData);
    this.formGroup.addControl(
      inputData.formControlName,
      this.formBuilder.control("")
    );
  }
```

```
  removeInputField(inputField: InputField) {
    this.formGroup.removeControl(inputField.formControlName);
    this.inputList = this.inputList.filter(field => field !== inputField);
  }
```

Main step is to call `removeControl` and `addControl` methods.
In your case you just should call `this.customerForm.removeControl(key)`.